# FileInfo.IsDir() isn't detecting directory

Tags: go

I have some code that walks through a directory to get the files, to operate on them and it uses `IsDir()` to skip directories. However, a directory isn't properly being detected:

```
err = filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if !f.IsDir() {
        fileList = append(fileList, path)
    }
    return nil
})
```

Error:

```
Put app/javascripts: read public/app/javascripts: is a directory
```

I'm on OSX. Here's the directory listing:

```
drwxr-xr-x@   6 me  staff     204 Sep 25 11:28 javascripts
```

Is there a better way to detect directories?

Comment: Ah...just used `f.Mode().String()` to print it out and it's `Lrwxr-xr-x`. Is there a good way to also exclude links that are directories?

Comment: Turns out it is a symlink. I was looking at the wrong dir :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong dir (confusing names). It was a symlink, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that file is a directory and also a symlink. In order to exclude files which match both conditions, you can use:

```
if !f.IsDir() && (f.Mode()&os.ModeSymlink) != os.ModeSymlink {
    ...
}
```