# os.Lstat Mode().IsDir() method on /var yields false

Tags: go, stat

The below works on all directories that I try except for `/var`. I thought maybe it was an ownership or permissions issue, but I am able to stat all other directories successfully inside of `/` without issues.

Why does this return false only for `/var`?

```
fmode, err := os.Lstat(*path)
if err != nil {
    displayErr(err)
}
if !fmode.Mode().IsDir() {
    displayError(fmt.Errorf("invalid directory provided for start point %s", *path))
}
```

Also, I recently switched to a Mac after using Ubuntu for many years. The code runs fine on Ubuntu but on the Mac it's always false. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe it is a symlink https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908277/fileinfo-isdir-isnt-detecting-directory

Comment: It *is* a symlink: `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root wheel  11 Jul  1  2011 /var@ -> private/var`

Comment: oh yes that's correct. Good link